# New Google Sign-In: Token used too late, 1452928807 > 1452897485

Tags: android, google-authentication, google-signin, android-authenticator, google-identity

I'm trying to implement the new Google Sign-In in a new app.

I implemented the official [example](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/SignInActivity.java) with additionally requesting the idToken.

Then I send the token to my server via a volley post request and verify it using the python example google posted [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth) (on the bottom of the page).

Everything is working fine except for the verification of the `idToken`. The following error occurs all the time:

> Token used too late, 1452928807 > 1452897485:

It is followed by the account information of the user.

It seems like the token is not refreshing - or something like that - because the expiring date of the token stays the same, even if I sign out and in again.

Google doesn't mention any method to refresh the token or what to do if it has expired.

Has anyone an how to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you check the accuracy of time/date on both mobile device and your server?

Comment: They are both accurate. But After some tests I found out that it works perfectly fine if I use the HttpApi to verify the token.
Maybe it is a bug in the python implementation

Answer (score 4):

Check your server time - this sort of thing is usually due to the Google servers and your server disagree on time.

Answer (score 0):

```
1452928807 
1/15/2016, 11:20:07 PM GMT-8:00

1452897485
1/15/2016, 2:38:05 PM GMT-8:00

1452928807 > 1452897485:
```

Probably timezone mismatch.

id token expires in 1hr. So looks like it's issued at 1:38PM (expire @2:38PM) and you used it at 2:20PM? (all in GMT-8) (I don't know why it took you almost an hour to try to verify it? :) Were you retrying?) I guess you are in GMT+1 time zone?

Could you confirm your server's time / timezone settings and paste the python code you used? Also server SDK version?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I cannot recreate the problem anymore. After updating my phone to Android 6 and creating a new project on googles developer console the problem was solved.